# Unwrapping a monad

Tags: haskell

Given the below program, I am having issues dealing with monads.

```
module Main 
where
import System.Environment
import System.Directory
import System.IO
import Text.CSV

--------------------------------------------------

exister :: String -> IO Bool
exister path = do
  fileexist <- doesFileExist path 
  direxist  <- doesDirectoryExist path
  return (fileexist || direxist )

--------------------------------------------------
slurp :: String -> IO String 
slurp path = do
  withFile path ReadMode (\handle -> do
                             contents <- hGetContents handle
                             last contents `seq` return contents )
--------------------------------------------------    
main :: IO ()
main = do
  [csv_filename] <- getArgs
  putStrLn (show csv_filename)
  csv_raw <- slurp csv_filename
  let csv_data = parseCSV csv_filename csv_raw

  printCSV csv_data -- unable to compile.
```

csv_data is an Either (parseerror) CSV type, and printCSV takes only CSV data.

---

Here's the ediff between the working version and the broken version.

```
***************
*** 27,30 ****
    csv_raw <- slurp csv_filename
    let csv_data = parseCSV csv_filename csv_raw

!   printCSV csv_data -- unable to compile. 
\ No newline at end of file
--- 27,35 ----
    csv_raw <- slurp csv_filename
    let csv_data = parseCSV csv_filename csv_raw

!   case csv_data of 
!     Left error -> putStrLn $ show error
!     Right csv_data -> putStrLn $ printCSV csv_data
!     
!   putStrLn "done"
!
```

reference: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/csv/0.1.2/doc/html/Text-CSV.html

Comment: The question doesn't seem to have anything to do with monads. :)

Comment: @Rotsor I was just going to post a comment reply, but it ballooned into an answer. The question is kinda sorta is about monads, but not really.

Comment: Paul, isn't the problem the poor name assigned `printCSV :: CSV -> String`?  It is a pure function, not a function to an IO type. If I write `putStrLn $ printCSV csv_data` for the last line, it compiles.

Comment: @applicative: yeah, I got kicked by the poor name. :-/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `case`.

```
main = do
    ...
    case csv_data of
        Left  err -> {- whatever you're going to do with an error -- print it, throw it as an exception, etc. -}
        Right csv -> printCSV csv
```

The `either` function is shorter (syntax-wise), but boils down to the same thing.

```
main = do
    ...
    either ({- error condition function -}) printCSV csv_data
```

Answer (score 17):

Regarding monads:

Yes, `Either a` is a monad. So simplifying the problem, you are basically asking for this:

```
main = print $ magicMonadUnwrap v

v :: Either String Int
v = Right 3

magicMonadUnwrap :: (Monad m) => m a -> a
magicMonadUnwrap = undefined
```

How do you define `magicMonadUnwrap`? Well, you see, it's different for each monad. Each one needs its own unwrapper. Many of these have the word "run" in them, for example, `runST`, `runCont`, or `runEval`. However, for some monads, it might not be safe to unwrap them (hence the need for differing unwrappers).

One implementation for lists would be `head`. But what if the list is empty? An unwrapper for `Maybe` is `fromJust`, but what if it's `Nothing`?

Similarly, the unwrapper for the `Either` monad would be something like:

```
fromRight :: Either a b -> b
fromRight (Right x) = x
```

But this unwrapper isn't safe: what if you had a `Left` value instead? (Left usually represents an error state, in your case, a parse error). So the best way to act upon an `Either` value it is to use the `either` function, or else use a case statement matching `Right` and `Left`, as Daniel Wagner illustrated.

***tl;dr***: there is no `magicMonadUnwrap`. If you're inside that same monad, you can use `<-`, but to truly extract the value from a monad...well...how you do it depends on which monad you're dealing with.

Comment: There is with TH, someone posted an implementation of a generic `Monad m => m a -> a`. Link: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/01/rewriting-monadic-expressions-with.html

Comment: @monadic: that technique is clever, but it's got a problem.  It only allows you to use `extract` within a Template Haskell splice which is then interpreted as some monad.  It basically just gives you a fancy `(>>=)`, which could be expected since `extract` is simply replaced by `join`.

Comment: @Dan: Interesting. I see your point, and it coheres better in my mind when I see what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

> *You must unlearn what you have learned.*
>
> Master Yoda.

Instead of thinking about, or searching for ways to "free", "liberate", "release", "unwrap" or "extract" normal Haskell values from effect-centric (usually monadic) contexts, learn how to use one of Haskell's more distinctive features - functions are *first-class values*:

- you can use functions like values of other types e.g. like `Bool`, `Char`, `Int`, `Integer` etc:

  ```
  arithOps :: [(String, Int -> Int -> Int)]
  arithOps =  zip ["PLUS","MINUS", "MULT", "QUOT", "REM"]
                  [(+), (-), (*), quot, rem]
  ```

For your purposes, what's more important is that functions can also be used as arguments e.g:

```
map          :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f xs     =  [ f x | x <- xs ]

filter       :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter p xs  =  [ x | x <- xs, p x ]
```

These *higher-order functions* are even available for use in effect-bearing contexts e.g:

```
import Control.Monad

liftM  :: Monad m => (a -> b)           -> (m a -> m b)
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c)      -> (m a -> m b -> m c)
liftM3 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c -> d) -> (m a -> m b -> m c -> m d)
```

...etc, which you can use to lift your regular Haskell functions:

```
do     .
       .
       .
   val <- liftM3 calculate this_M that_M other_M
       .
       .
       .
```

Of course, the direct approach also works:

```
do     .
       .
       .
   x <- this_M
   y <- that_M
   z <- other_M
   let val =  calculate x y z
       .
       .
       .
```

As your skills develop, you'll find yourself delegating more and more code to ordinary functions and leaving the effects to a vanishingly-small set of entities defined in terms of functors, applicatives, monads, arrows, etc as you progress towards Haskell mastery.

---

You're not convinced? Well, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62572475/13679816) a brief note of how effects used to be handled in Haskell - [there's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62557499/13679816) also a longer description of how Haskell arrived at the monadic interface. Alternately, you could look at [Standard ML](https://www.smlnj.org/sml.html), [OCaml](https://ocaml.org), and other similar languages - who knows, maybe you'll be happier with using them...

Comment: "everything is better with [`do`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/do-notation/info)". :)

Comment: ...including `sh` and `C`?  ;-)