# How to take out a value out of a monad in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

Is there any way to take "things" out of a monad?

I am developing a game, and I am now trying to understand about databases. I found [`happstack`](http://www.happstack.com/page/view-page-slug/1/happstack) really nice, but I can't get the thing.

For example, I have this function (hope you are familiar with `happstack`)

```
getAllThings :: MonadIO m => m [Thing]
getAllThings = do
            elems <- query GetThings
            return elems
```

So I get `m [Things]`, but I can't use this in my model! For instance

```
doSomeThingWithThings :: [Thing] -> Something
```

I googled this and I found nothing.

Comment: You may enjoy [my comments about the imaginary `magicMonadUnwrap`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154518/unwrapping-a-monad/7156230#7156230) (answer to a similar StackOverflow question)

Comment: There is a way to take "things" out of a monad - use [Standard ML](https://www.smlnj.org/sml.html).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are not supposed to exit IO monad this way (except `unsafePerformIO` function), but you can still use your function inside it:

```
process :: MonadIO m => m ()
process = do
          elems <- getAllThings
          let smth = doSomeThingWithThings elems
          -- ...
```

Comment: You can think of it like this: your entire program is IO monad, and your model is bunch of pure functions which are executed inside it.

Comment: Yes!! after re thinking my question with your answers, I understand that it has to be this way!, my game is (as you said) pure functions, but user interface is the real ugly world, so the persistence part has to be too!

Answer (score 2):

After `elems <- query GetThings` the elems is `[Thing]` so `<-` inside do is about getting things out of monad (called bind operation). The last statement `return` put things inside a monad. So either you can call you other function after getting elems and before `return` or where ever you are calling `getAllThings` you can use extract the value using `<-` from the monad and pass it to your function