# Generic 'unwrap' function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

When I use `fmap` over a value, it essentially "unboxes" that value, applies the function to it, and boxes it back up.

For example:

```
-- returns Just 8
fmap (+3) (Just 5)
```

Is there any function that gives me the value without boxing it back up?

```
-- returns 8
fmap_2 (+3) (Just 5)
```

Granted, I don't know how this would work for arrays, but it would be useful for `Either`s and `Maybe`s, for starters. I could also use it to mix Monads easily:

```
-- myfunc :: Maybe Int

-- if myfunc returned a Just, show it and then print it. Otherwise, print 'Nothing'.
putStrLn . fmap show $ myfunc
```

Or is there another standard way of mixing Monads?

Comment: No, there's no standard way of mixing monads. There cannot be. Monads do not commute.

However, *some* monads can be mixed in their own special ways. An established method of packaging such a special way of monad mixing is called a monad transformer. There are several libraries of monad transformers out there, and extensive literature. Just google "monad transformers".

Comment: Take a look: [How to extract value from monadic action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567743/how-to-extract-value-from-monadic-action)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For extracting `Maybe` use `maybe`:

```
maybe 0 (+3) $ Just 5
>>> 8
maybe 0 (+3) Nothing
>>> 0
```

You should use `fromJust` only when getting a `Nothing` must be considered as an abnormal situation. Don't evolve a habit of crashing your program without a really good reason to. The `Maybe` and `Either` are there exactly to help you avoid that.

For `Either` there is a function `either`:

```
either (*2) (+2) $ Left 3
>>> 6
either (*2) (+2) $ Right 3
>>> 5
```

Please note that in correct code you won't need to extract monads often. That's kinda whole point about them and Haskell has to offer all the tools you may need to work with monadic values as if they were extracted.

Comment: also, there's `fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a`

Answer (score 5):

This function cannot exist for *all* functors. Even for simple ones like `Maybe`, it would not work if you had a `Nothing`. For `IO`, this would let you do arbitrary IO in your program and be decidedly unsafe. Finally, for some slightly weirder functors (like `(->) e` which is just a function taking an argument of type `e`), this would not even make any sense.

However, for some types that *are* functors, this function exists. For example, there is a function called `fromJust` that has a type `Maybe a -> a`. However, if you pass this function a `Nothing`, you will get a runtime error.

So, a function like this could exist for some types that are also instances of `Functor`, but it does not make sense for the `Functor` class itself.

Answer (score 2):

import Control.Comonad ([extract](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/comonad/latest/doc/html/Control-Comonad.html#v%3aextract))