# haskell read a file in array of Ints

Tags: haskell

I have a homework to sort a numbers that are to extract from a file.

Simple File Format:

```
45673
57879
28392
54950
23280
...
```

So I want to extract `[Int]` and than to apply my sort-function radix to it.
I write in my file

```
readLines :: FilePath -> IO [String]
readLines = fmap lines . readFile
makeInteger :: [String] -> [Int]
makeInteger = map read
```

and then I write in the command line

```
radix (makeInteger (readlines("111.txt")))
```

and then I have, off course, problems with type conversion from `IO String` to `String`. I tried to write

```
makeInteger :: IO [String] -> [Int]
makeInteger = map read
```

but it also doesn't work.

How do I work with pure data outside the `IO` monad?

Comment: As I wrote above, I have a problem with incompatibility of IO [String] and [String]
The answer of compiler: Couldn't match expected type (String) with actual type IO String
So I cannot apply function makeInteger to the results of function readlines

Comment: This is probably the most common question. Notice `IO [String]` is an action, not a bunch of strings (think, `getStr` from C).  You RUN the action, not convert it to a string.

Comment: I understand (somehow) the problem, but don't know how to write correctly to get [Int] in the end

Comment: If you start with an `IO [String]`, you can't get an `[Int]` as result. What you can do is applying a plain `[String] -> [Int]` function to values in the `IO` monad.

Comment: You're able to convert an `IO String` into an `IO [String]` using `fmap lines`.  Here, `lines` has the type `String -> [String]`.  You have a function with type `[String] -> [Int]`, how would you apply it to `IO [String]`?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand properly what you mean. could you please write an example of code?

Comment: The function `readFile` has type `FilePath -> IO String`. You've composed it with the function `fmap lines`, which has the type `Functor f => f String -> f [String]`, and in this case gets turned into `IO String -> IO [String]` using IO's Functor instance (since `readLine` returns `IO String`). So, what would be the type of `fmap makeInteger` using IO's Functor instance? Since `makeInteger` has type `[String] -> [Int]`, you would get `IO [String] -> IO [Int]`. So you can compose `fmap makeInteger . readLines` to get the result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567743/how-to-extract-value-from-monadic-action), "the inability to "escape" from the monad is essential for monads like IO".

So you need to do something like:

```
readLines :: FilePath -> IO [String]
readLines = fmap lines . readFile
makeInteger :: [String] -> [Int]
makeInteger = map read

main = do
  content <- readLines "111.txt"
  return (radix $ makeInteger content)
```

This "takes the content out" of the IO monad, applies the function you want on it, then puts it back into the IO monad again.

Comment: By the way, this `do` block is equivalent to `fmap (radix . makeInteger) (readLines "111.txt")`, thus illustrating what bheklir said in the comments above.

Comment: @duplode I hope user reads your solution, it definitely is the one that makes the most sense given his readLines method...