# Get value from IO String in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, functional-programming

I have a function with signature `read_F95_src :: String -> IO [String]`. This function is used elsewhere and cannot be changed.

I am reading in source lines and associated with a label as such `src_lines = read_F95_src templ_src_name`, which compiles and runs fine.

The problem is that I now have a function which takes in `[String]`, and no matter how I try, I can't figure out a way to get the `[String]` value from `src_lines`.

Comment: another duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567743/how-to-extract-value-from-monadic-action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't "extract" a value from `IO`.  Instead you lift the rest of your computation into `IO` using `fmap`.  So

```
read_F95_src :: String -> IO [String]

doSomethingWithStringList :: [String] -> Whatever

fmap doSomethingWithStringList :: IO [String] -> IO Whatever

fmap doSomethingWithStringList . read_F95_src :: String -> IO Whatever
```

You should get used to this pattern because it's going to happen to you a lot when you use Haskell.  For example, if you want to do something with the `IO Whatever` you'll have to use the same trick again!

Answer (score 1):

```
let src_lines = read_F95_src templ_src_name
(ss::[String]) <- src_lines
{- do whatever with ss -}
```

Comment: This gives me this `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)`

Answer (score 1):

Extract the `[String]` like this inside a do block:

```
some_function :: IO [String]
some_function = do
  dat <- read_F95_src "some data" -- Now the dat will contain the [String]
  -- Now do all your stuffs on dat and return whatever you want to.
  return dat
```

Once you have extracted the `dat` inside the function, you can apply other functions on it according to your logic and finally return whatever you need to.

Comment: Keep in mind that this function will again return an `IO [String]`, so if you want to do something with the list, you need to do it after you read it but before you return it. `dat` is – inside this function – a `[String]` value without the `IO`.

Comment: But dat is only within the scope of the do is it not? I need to use the `[String]` later in the program.

Comment: @Geesh_SO Create functions which operates on `[String]` according to your logic and call it inside this function. This way you will also separate pure and impure code.