# Is there a way to unwrap a type from an IO monad?

Tags: haskell, io, monads, io-monad

I have this very simple function

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

getJson :: IO B.ByteString
getJson = B.readFile jsonFile

readJFile :: IO (Maybe Response)
readJFile =  parsing >>= (\d ->
             case d of
                 Left err -> return Nothing
                 Right ps -> return (Just ps))
    where parsing = fmap eitherDecode getJson :: IO (Either String Response)
```

where `jsonFile` is a path to a file on my harddrive (pardon the lack of do-notation, but I found this more clear to work with)

my question is; is there a way for me to ditch the `IO` part so I can work with the bytestring alone?

I know that you can pattern match on certain monads like `Either` and `Maybe` to get their values out, but can you do something similar with `IO`?

Or voiced differently: is there a way for me to make `readJFile` return `Maybe Response` without the IO?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567743/how-to-extract-value-from-monadic-action

Comment: I'm not talking about built-in stuff though, I'm just asking for a way to do it, that I could perhaps construct myself; the way my code looks now I have to drag that IO monad with me through 5 functions and to be fair it clutters it up a lot, especially considering the fact that I only perform IO operations in that ONE function and nowhere else

Comment: You never need to "drag a monad" through any functions, unless they all need to actually do IO. Just lift the entire chain into the monad with `fmap` (or `liftM` / `liftM2` / ...).

Comment: @ElectricCoffee If the other functions don't do IO, then they shouldn't be in IO. Make them depend on the bytestring (i.e., of type `B.ByteString -> ...`) and then use a single IO action to combine the reading with the processing.

Comment: updated the code for clarification

Comment: No. `readJFile` does IO, so it must have an IO type. But you can abstract it over the bytestring instead, as I said above.

Comment: but it doesn't do io, the `getJson` function does, all `readJFile` does is interpret the received data

Comment: Of course `readJFile` does some `IO`, if it invokes `getJson`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on my comments, here's how you can do it:

```
getJson :: IO B.ByteString
getJson = B.readFile jsonFile -- as before

readJFile :: B.ByteString -> Maybe Response -- look, no IO
readJFile b = case eitherDecode b of
                Left err -> Nothing
                Right ps -> Just ps
```

In the end, you combine everything in one IO action again:

```
getAndProcess :: IO (Maybe Response)
getAndProcess = do
  b <- getJson
  return (readJFile b)
```

Comment: it's clean, it's simple, I like it! unfortunately it doesn't work at all

Comment: @ElectricCoffee The error you post seems to have little to do with my code. It mentions a line `Left err -> return Nothing` which doesn't appear in my code, and then another line `Right ps -> return Just ps` which also doesn't appear in my code.

Answer (score 4):

You never need to "drag a monad" through any functions, unless they all need to actually do IO. Just lift the entire chain into the monad with `fmap` (or `liftM` / `liftM2` / ...).

For instance,

```
f1 :: B.ByteString -> K
f2 :: K -> I
f3 :: K -> J
f4 :: I -> J -> M
```

and your entire thing is supposed to be like

```
m :: M
m = let k = "f1 getJson"
    in f4 (f2 k) (f3 k)
```

The you can simply do

```
m = fmap (\b -> let k = f1 b
                in f4 (f2 k) (f3 k) )
    getJson
```

Incidentally, this might look nicer with `do` notation:

```
m = do
  b <- getJson
  return $ let k = f1 b
           in f4 (f2 k) (f3 k)
```

---

Concerning you edit and the question

> is there a way for me to make `readJFile` return `Maybe Response` without the `IO`?

*No*, that can't possibly work, because `readJFile` does need to do IO. There's no way escaping from the `IO` monad then, that's the whole point of it! (Well, there is `unsafePerformIO` as Ricardo says, but this is definitely not a valid application for it.)

If it's the clunkiness of unpacking `Maybe` values in the `IO` monad, and the signatures with parens in them, you may want to looks at the [`MaybeT` transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#v%3aMaybeT).

```
readJFile' :: MaybeT IO Response
readJFile' = do
   b <- liftIO getJson
   case eitherDecode b of
     Left err -> mzero
     Right ps -> return ps
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes, there is a way. Accompanied by a lot of "but", but there is. You're asking for what it's called an **unsafe IO operation**: [System.IO.Unsafe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v%3aunsafePerformIO). It's used to write wrappers when calling to external libraries usually, it's not something to resort to in regular Haskell code.

Basically, you can call `unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a` which does exactly what you want, it strips out the `IO` part and gives you back wrapped value of type `a`. But, if you look at the documentation, there are a number of requirements which you should guarantee yourself to the system, which all end up in the same idea: even though you performed the operation via IO, the answer should be the result of a function, as expected from any other haskell function which does not operate in `IO`: it should always have the same result without side effects, only based on the input values.

Here, given your code, **this is obviously NOT the case**, since you're reading from a file. You should just continue working within the IO monad, by calling your `readJFile` from within another function with result type `IO something`. Then, you'll be able to read the value within the `IO` wrapper (being in `IO` yourself), work on it, and then re-wrap the result in another `IO` when returning.

Comment: *Never* recommend `unsafePerformIO` to a beginner. Even just mentioning makes it seem like a reasonable alternative in some cases, which it is not. A beginner never needs to use, or know about, `unsafePerformIO`. I'm mentioning this because for me and other people, knowing about `unsafePerformIO` when we learned Haskell actually made it harder to learn, because it gave the impression that you're supposed to "break out" of the IO monad at some point, which you are not.

Comment: Did you actually READ my answer, mr easy downvote? I did not recommend it, I simply stated a fact. My answer is not promoting it nor wrong. Don't upvote it if you don't like it. Unsafe operations are required in some cases, when you have to interact with external libraries (maybe writing wrappers for them). Ok, it's not beginners stuff, but it's not up to you to decide what I should and should not tell people about, as long as it is correct.

Comment: I'd like to remark also that SO is meant to be a repository of answers, and this holds whoever is searching for information. Even though he is a beginner and won't need unsafePerformIO, mentioning it for reference might be of help to people actually needing it, in future @kqr.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no safe way to get a value out of the IO monad. Instead you should do the work inside the IO monad by applying functions with fmap or bind (>>=). Also you should use decode instead of eitherDecode when you want your result to be in Maybe.

```
getJson :: IO B.ByteString
getJson = B.readFile jsonFile

parseResponse :: B.ByteString -> Maybe Response
parseResponse = decode

readJFile :: IO (Maybe Response)
readJFile = fmap parseResponse getJSON
```

You could also use do notation if that is clearer to you:

```
readJFile :: IO (Maybe Response)
readJFile = do
    bytestring <- getJson
    return $ decode bytestring
```

Note that you dont even need the parseResponse function since readJFile specifies the type.