# Haskell Convert from IO a to m a

Tags: haskell, monads

I want to convert a monadic value into a monadic value of a other Monad class.

Lets say I have a instance declaration:

```
    instance ClassM TypeT where
        funcX = abc >>= \x -> return (x)
```

ClassM : is a own monad defined class
TypeT  : is a own defined type/data with a monad instance implementation 
abc    : is of type IO a

how do i convert the monadic value of abc::IO a
to a monadic value of classM m => m a
aka m1 a -> m2 a (where m1 is not m2)(example: IO 5 -> Just 5)

my implementation of funcX is obviously not correct. If it is possible, what should be the correct implementation?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: For `m a` to `IO a`, have a look at `liftIO` in `MonadIO`. More generally, `lift` from `MonadTrans`. Otherwise, maybe you'll be interested in the package `mmorph`.

Comment: You're probably aware of this, but just saying: `\x -> return x` is simply `return`, and by the monad laws `v >>= return` must be `v` again, always. So at the moment you have just `funcX = abc` there.

Comment: It's Not Possible By Design. You cannot unwrap IO off a value. It's forever, like diamonds. Perhaps if you tell us what problem you are trying to solve, we'll be able to help you.

Comment: [How do I convert `IO Int` to `Int`?](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FAQ#How_do_I_convert_IO_Int_to_Int.3F)

Comment: See also: [How to extract value from monadic action](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8567743/791604) and [taking out a value out of a monad? haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7314789/791604)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Monad "class" it is not an "class" from objects.

You are asking about `Comonads`->`Monad` transformation: [Comonad package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-4.0/docs/Control-Comonad.html)

```
convert :: (Comonad w, Monad m) => w a -> m a
convert = return . extract
```

In any case you can't have comonad from IO

You could use some hackery using `unsafePerormIO`

Comment: On `unsafePerformIO`: you *could*, but in most cases you shouldn't.

Answer (score 7):

`Monad` the class represents all things which are monads---it's an adjective more than a noun. If you'd like to convert a particular monad into a value which is generic in all monads that type would look like one of these

```
Monad m => IO a       -> m a
Monad m => Maybe a    -> m a
Monad m => [a]        -> m a
Monad m => Either e a -> m a
```

and it's in general impossible, though [one type of very special monads](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free) has this property.

Another thing you might do is use a `Monad` transformer which `IO` at the bottom. This means that you layer another monad "on top of" `IO`. This lets you have the general operation

```
lift :: MonadTrans t => m a -> t m a     -- notice that t takes two parameters
lift :: IO a -> MyTransformer IO a       -- specializing the generic function
```

and, depending on what `MyTransformer` is, the specific operation

```
runMyTransformer :: MyTransformer m a -> m a
runMyTransformer :: MyTransformer IO a -> IO a   -- specialized
```

For instance, the very simplest `MonadTrans` is `IdT`.

```
newtype IdT m a = IdT { runIdT :: m a } deriving Functor

instance Monad m => Monad (IdT m) where
  return a = IdT (return a)
  IdT ma >>= f = IdT (ma >>= runIdT . f) 

instance MonadTrans IdT where
  lift ma = IdT ma
```

Giving us the operations

```
lift   :: IO a -> IdT IO a
runIdT :: IdT IO a -> IO a
```

which are just inverses of one another, in this case. In general the behavior can be much more complex.