# Extracting a Maybe value in IO

Tags: haskell, io, monads, option-type

Given the following:

```
> (liftM2 fromMaybe) (ioError $ userError "OOPS") (return $ Just "ok")
```

ghci gives me

```
*** Exception: user error (OOPS)
```

Of course, fromMaybe is working correctly:

```
> (liftM2 fromMaybe) (return $ "not me") (return $ Just "ok")
"ok"
```

But it seems that the IO operation is being carried out and then discarded:

```
> (liftM2 fromMaybe) (putStrLn "computing.." >> "discarded") (return $ Just "ok")
computing..
"ok"
```

Why is this happening? Is there any way to make the IO monad lazier?

Specifically, given `value :: IO (Maybe a)` what's a (clean, concise) way to say

```
result <- (liftM2 fromMaybe) err value
```

and have it unpack result or throw an IOError accordingly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know that making `IO` lazier is the right direction here. What you seem to want to do is first get at the `Maybe`, then eliminate it. This can be written several ways, here's one option:

```
test :: IO (Maybe a) -> IO a
test = (>>= maybe (ioError $ userError "oops") return)
```

Answer (score 10):

If you translate from `liftM2` to do-notation, it's obvious why your code fails:

```
do x <- ioError $ userError "OOPS"
   y <- return $ Just "ok"
   return $ fromMaybe x y
```

This will never go past the first line, as it's unconditionally throwing an exception.

[Anthony's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8541199/98117) will work fine, but if you don't care about the specific exception thrown, you can also use pattern matching:

```
do Just result <- value
```

If the pattern doesn't match, this will call `fail`, which in the case of the `IO` monad throws an exception.

```
> Just x <- return Nothing
*** Exception: user error (Pattern match failure in do expression at <interactive>:1:0-5)
```

Answer (score 5):

> what's a (clean, concise) way to ... unpack [the] result or throw an IOError accordingly?

I recommend you avoid relying on throwing errors. Instead, handle the "error" explicitly:

```
maybeM :: Monad m => m b -> (a -> m b) -> m (Maybe a) -> m b
maybeM err f value = do
  x <- value
  case x of
    Just y  -> f y
    Nothing -> err

-- This can be written simply as:
maybeM err f value = do
  x <- value
  maybe err f x

-- or even shorter! This is starting to look like Anthony's answer :)
maybeM err f value = value >>= maybe err f
```

The function's inputs and types should speak for themselves. You use it by giving it an action to perform for the `Nothing` case, or a function to perform on the value inside for the `Just` case. For your particular inputs this would look like:

```
maybeM (ioError $ userError "OOPS") return (return $ Just "ok")
```

So if you *absolutely must*, then the "concise way to unpack the result or throw an IOError" would be:

```
-- compare to fromJust, a function to be avoided
fromJustIO :: IO (Maybe a) -> IO a
fromJustIO = maybeM (ioError $ userError "OOPS") return
```

Notice how the type signature for this is practically `Maybe a -> a`, which is the essence of [`magicMonadUnwrap :: Monad m => m a -> a`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154518/unwrapping-a-monad/7156230#7156230), which should set off some red flags. However, you can use this atrocity in a simple manner:

```
result <- fromJustIO value
```

Although again, I strongly discourage the use of exceptions here. Try handling errors in a more elegant way than simply exploding, by using `maybeM` and providing an IO action to execute in the event of failure.

Comment: Thanks for the concern, but it's a bit unfounded. I'm throwing the errors in a number of second-tier functions that each do their little bit of IO to grab some configuration. The first-tier configuration function tries them all with a "catch" and formats any errors nicely. It allows me to keep my error handling in one place without needing to thread a "handleErr" function through all the second-tier functions. In such a scenario, are errors still a bad idea?

Comment: So8res: personally I'd have the second-tier functions produce `Maybe` values, and then the first-tier config function can either lump them together with something like `sequence` or `<$>` and `<*>`, or handle each potential error separately, as desired. It's a matter of taste, but in my opinion, errors are almost always a bad idea in Haskell, since we have powerful abstractions that let us compose `Maybe`. The throw/catch control flow mechanism doesn't match the FP style that Haskell encourages.