# Haskell: Trapped in IO monad

Tags: haskell, io, monads, pure-function

I am trying to parse a file using the `parseFile` function found in the the `haskell-src-exts` package.

I am trying to work with the output of `parseFile` which is of course `IO`, but I can't figure out how to get around the `IO`.  I found a function `liftIO` but I am not sure if that is the solution in this situation.  Here is the code below.

```
import Language.Haskell.Exts.Syntax
import Language.Haskell.Exts 
import Data.Map hiding (foldr, map)
import Control.Monad.Trans

increment :: Ord a => a -> Map a Int -> Map a Int
increment a = insertWith (+) a 1

fromName :: Name -> String
fromName (Ident s) = s
fromName (Symbol st) = st

fromQName :: QName -> String
fromQName (Qual _ fn) = fromName fn
fromQName (UnQual n) = fromName n

fromLiteral :: Literal -> String
fromLiteral (Int int) = show int

fromQOp :: QOp -> String
fromQOp (QVarOp qn) = fromQName qn

vars :: Exp -> Map String Int
vars (List (x:xs)) = vars x
vars (Lambda _ _ e1) = vars e1
vars (EnumFrom e1) = vars e1
vars (App e1 e2) = unionWith (+) (vars e1) (vars e2)
vars (Let _ e1) = vars e1
vars (NegApp e1) = vars e1
vars (Var qn) = increment (fromQName qn) empty
vars (Lit l) = increment (fromLiteral l) empty
vars (Paren e1) = vars e1
vars (InfixApp exp1 qop exp2) = 
                 increment (fromQOp qop) $ 
                     unionWith (+) (vars exp1) (vars exp2)



match :: [Match] -> Map String Int
match rhss = foldr (unionWith (+) ) empty 
                    (map (\(Match  a b c d e f) -> rHs e) rhss)

rHS :: GuardedRhs -> Map String Int
rHS (GuardedRhs _ _ e1) = vars e1

rHs':: [GuardedRhs] -> Map String Int
rHs' gr = foldr (unionWith (+)) empty 
                 (map (\(GuardedRhs a b c) -> vars c) gr)

rHs :: Rhs -> Map String Int
rHs (GuardedRhss gr) = rHs' gr
rHs (UnGuardedRhs e1) = vars e1

decl :: [Decl] -> Map String Int
decl decls =  foldr (unionWith (+) ) empty 
                     (map fun decls )
    where fun (FunBind f) = match f
          fun _ = empty

pMod' :: (ParseResult Module) -> Map String Int
pMod' (ParseOk (Module _ _ _ _ _ _ dEcl)) = decl dEcl 

pMod :: FilePath -> Map String Int
pMod = pMod' . liftIO . parseFile
```

I just want to be able to use the `pMod'` function on the output of `parseFile`.

Note that all the types and data constructors can be found at http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-exts/1.13.5/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Exts-Syntax.html if that helps.   Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154518/unwrapping-a-monad .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Once inside IO, there's no escape.

Use `fmap`:

```
-- parseFile :: FilePath -> IO (ParseResult Module)
-- pMod' :: (ParseResult Module) -> Map String Int
-- fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

-- fmap pMod' (parseFile filePath) :: IO (Map String Int)

pMod :: FilePath -> IO (Map String Int)
pMod = fmap pMod' . parseFile
```

---

(*addition*:) As explained in [great answer by Levi Pearson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18217606/849891), there's also

```
Prelude Control.Monad> :t liftM
liftM :: (Monad m) => (a1 -> r) -> m a1 -> m r
```

But that's no black magic either. Consider:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> let g f = (>>= return . f)
Prelude Control.Monad> :t g
g :: (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

So your function can also be written as

```
pMod fpath = fmap pMod' . parseFile $ fpath
     = liftM pMod' . parseFile $ fpath
     = (>>= return . pMod') . parseFile $ fpath   -- pushing it...
     = parseFile fpath >>= return . pMod'         -- that's better

pMod :: FilePath -> IO (Map String Int)
pMod fpath = do
    resMod <- parseFile fpath
    return $ pMod' resMod
```

whatever *you* find more intuitive <sub>(remember, `(.)` has the highest precedence, just below the function application)</sub>.

Incidentally, the `>>= return . f` bit is how [`liftM`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM) is actually implemented, only in `do`-notation; and it really shows the equivalency of `fmap` and `liftM`, because for any monad it should hold that:

```
fmap f m  ==  m >>= (return . f)
```

Answer (score 14):

To give a more general answer than Will's (which was certainly correct and to-the-point), you typically 'lift' operations *into* a Monad rather than taking values *out* of them in order to apply pure functions to monadic values.

It so happens that `Monad`s (theoretically) are a specific kind of `Functor`. `Functor` describes the class of types that represent mappings of objects and operations into a different context. A data type that is an instance of `Functor` maps objects into its context via its data constructors and it maps operations into its context via the `fmap` function. To implement a true functor, `fmap` must work in such a way that lifting the identity function into the functor context does not change the values in the functor context, and lifting two functions composed together produces the same operation within the functor context as lifting the functions separately and then composing them within the functor context.

Many, many Haskell data types naturally form functors, and `fmap` provides a universal interface to lift functions so that they apply 'evenly' throughout the functorized data without worrying about the form of the particular `Functor` instance. A couple of great examples of this are the list type and the `Maybe` type; `fmap` of a function into a list context is exactly the same as the familiar `map` operation on lists, and `fmap` of a function into a `Maybe` context will apply the function normally for a `Just a` value and do nothing for a `Nothing` value, allowing you to perform operations on it without worrying about which it is.

Having said all that, by a quirk of history the Haskell Prelude doesn't currently require `Monad` instances to also have a `Functor` instance, so `Monad` provides a family of functions that also lift operations into monadic contexts. The operation `liftM` does the same thing that `fmap` does for `Monad` instances that are also `Functor` instances (as they should be). But `fmap` and `liftM` only lift single-argument functions. `Monad` helpfully provides a family of `liftM2` -- `liftM5` functions that lift multi-argument functions into monadic context in the same way.

Finally, you asked about `liftIO`, which brings in the related idea of monad *transformers*, in which multiple `Monad` instances are combined in a single data type by applying monad mappings to already-monadic values, forming a kind of *stack* of monadic mappings over a basic pure type.  The **mtl** library provides one implementation of this general idea, and in its module `Control.Monad.Trans` it defines two classes, `MonadTrans t` and `Monad m => MonadIO m`.  The `MonadTrans` class provides a single function, `lift`, that gives access to operations in the next higher monadic "layer" in the stack, i.e. `(MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a`.  The `MonadIO` class provides a single function, `liftIO`, that provides access to `IO` monad operations from any "layer" in the stack, i.e. `IO a -> m a`. These make working with monad transformer stacks much more convenient at the cost of having to provide a lot of transformer instance declarations when new `Monad` instances are introduced to a stack.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! I feel like I understand monads and functors a little more now (not that I understood them at all before).

Comment: Part of the reason I answer questions here is to help reinforce these concepts in my mind so that they come more naturally while programming! After you think about how the different type classes work together, really opaque Haskell code becomes suddenly transparent.  Good luck!