# How to handle IO return values properly in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, functional-programming

Hi i have a very noob question, lets say i want to create a game when you have to answer questions, i wrote this

```
data Question = Question { answer::String, text::String }
data Player = Player { name::String, points::String }

answerQuestion ::  Question -> Player -> Player 
answerQuestion question player
    | isCorrect question playerAnswer = Player (name player) (points player + 1)
    | otherwise = player
    where
      playerAnswer = do
          putStrLn text(question)
          getLine

isCorrect ::  Question -> String -> Bool 
isCorrect question try = try == answer(question)
```

now playerAnswer has type `IO String` so do i have to call `isCorrect` inside the `do` block ? Is there another way to parse `IO String` into `String` ?

In case of first i am feeling like loosing all the benefits from functional programming because i will end up writing my entire code in `do` blocks in order to access the `String` value

Comment: your trouble start when you realize that `answerQuestion` will not compile (as `playerAnswer` is an `IO String` action)  - that's why you should split up the functionality and add the answer as an additional `String` argument to your `answerQuestion` IMO

Comment: Nice approach, so how can i perform a string match for an `IO String` answer against a `answer(question)` `String`

Comment: btw. `points :: String` - is this really what you want?

Comment: I recommend that you read ["Inside My World (Ode to Functor and Monad)"](http://blog.jle.im/entry/inside-my-world-ode-to-functor-and-monad).  It addresses this topic very well, I think.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7154518 .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>Note: This post is written in literate Haskell. You can save it as Game.lhs and try it in your GHCi.</sup>

> now playerAnswer has type `IO String` so do i have to call isCorrect inside the do block?

Yes, if you stay on that course.

> Is there another way to parse `IO String` into `String`?

None that's not unsafe. An `IO String` is something that gives you a `String`, but whatever uses the `String` has to stay in `IO`.

> In case of first i am feeling like loosing all the benefits from functional programming because i will end up writing my entire code in do blocks in order to access the String value .

This can happen if you don't take measurements early. However, let's approach this from a top-down approach. First, let's introduce some type aliases so that it's clear whether we look at a `String` in as an answer or a name:

```
> type Text   = String
> type Answer = String
> type Name   = String
> type Points = Int    -- points are usually integers
```

Your original types stay the same:

```
> data Question = Question { answer :: Answer
>                          , text   :: Text } deriving Show
> data Player   = Player { name   :: Name
>                        , points :: Points } deriving Show
```

Now let's think about a single turn of the game. You want to ask the player a question, get his answer, and if he's right, add some points:

```
> gameTurn :: Question -> Player -> IO Player
> gameTurn q p = do
>    askQuestion q
>    a <- getAnswer
>    increasePointsIfCorrect q p a
```

This will be enough to fill your game with a single turn. Let's fill those functions with life. `askQuestions` and `getAnswer` change the world: they print something on the terminal and ask for user input. They *have* to be in `IO` at some point:

```
> askQuestion :: Question -> IO ()
> askQuestion q = putStrLn (text q)

> getAnswer :: IO String
> getAnswer = getLine
```

Before we actually define `increasePointsIfCorrect`, let's think about a version that does not use `IO`, again, in a slightly more abstract way:

```
> increasePointsIfCorrect' :: Question -> Player -> Answer -> Player
> increasePointsIfCorrect' q p a =
>    if isCorrect q a
>       then increasePoints p
>       else p
```

By the way, if you watch closely, you'll notice that `increasePointsIfCorrect'` is actually a single game turn. After all, it's checks the answer and increases the points. Speaking of:

```
> increasePoints :: Player -> Player
> increasePoints (Player n p) = Player n (p + 1)

> isCorrect :: Question -> Answer -> Bool
> isCorrect q a = answer q == a
```

We now defined several functions that don't use `IO`. All that's missing is `increasePointsIfCorrect`:

```
> increasePointsIfCorrect :: Question -> Player -> Answer -> IO Player
> increasePointsIfCorrect q p a = return (increasePointsIfCorrect' q p a)
```

You can check this now with a simple short game:

```
> theQuestion = Question { text   = "What is your favourite programming language?"
>                        , answer = "Haskell (soon)"}
> thePlayer   = Player { name   = "Alberto Pellizzon"
>                      , points = 306 }
>
> main :: IO ()
> main = gameTurn theQuestion thePlayer >>= print
```

There are other ways to handle this, but I guess this is one of the easier ones for beginners.

Either way, what's nice is that we could now test all the logic without using `IO`. For example:

```
prop_increasesPointsOnCorrectAnswer q p =
   increasePointsIfCorrect' q p (answer q) === increasePoints p

prop_doesnChangePointsOnWrongAnswer q p a = a /= answer q ==>
   increasePointsIfCorrect' q p a === p

ghci> quickCheck prop_increasesPointsOnCorrectAnswer 
OK. Passed 100 tests.
ghci> quickCheck prop_doesnChangePointsOnWrongAnswer 
OK. Passed 100 tests.
```

Implementing those tests completely is out of scope of this question though.

#### Exercises

- Tell the player whether his answer was correct.
- Add `playGame :: [Question] -> Player -> IO ()`, which asks several questions after another and tells the player the final score.
- Ask the player for his/her name and store it in the initial player.
- (Very Hard for a beginner) Try to find a way so that you can either play a game automatically  (for example for testing), or "against" a human. Hint: Look for "domain specific language".

Comment: One of these days I'm going to write a normal sized answer.

Comment: or just write some script to extract all your answers, string them together and publish "Haskell the ultimate reference to programming the universe and all the rest" ;)

Comment: @Carsten Sure. "In the beginning, my account was created. This has made a lot of people very angry and been widely regarded as a bad move.".

Comment: Hi guys thank you all for your answers, it will took me some time to read and understand everything, one thing that i noticed is that all 3 answers are considerably different and maybe this means that it not an easy topic :D, i will accept this as the right answer(of course because it is the longest) when i understand it completely

Answer (score 1):

as an alternative you can *promote* `answerQuestion` to an action as well:

```
answerQuestion ::  Question -> Player -> IO Player 
answerQuestion question player =
    answer <- playerAnswer
    if isCorrect question answer
    then return $ Player (name player) (points player + 1)
    else return player
    where
      playerAnswer = do
          putStrLn $ text question
          getLine
```

so yes you could say that in this case you should call `isCorrect` from inside a `do` block

Comment: This is a viable solution what i don't like about that is 
1 - writing the entire function in an imperative way (if / then / else) 
2 - i want  `askQuestion` to return a Player
3 - if i have to call `answerQuestion` from another function i also have to call it inside a do block and so on

Comment: well you can rewrite it to `case` if you like but it's just the same as yours ... and once you enter `do` it will always look very imperative - btw: what is your question then?

Comment: So the real problem here is that i am not able to perform a match with an IO String against a String and in order to do that from what i know i have to "covert" the IO String into a String and this can be done only inside a do block but doing that will make my code to be only inside that and to me it seems an hack, i am talking from a very beginner prospective and you actually already answer my question so i am going to accept it, just trying to dig deeper in this problem

Comment: well not exactly - you don't convert some values - you should think of `IO String` as an *action* that you can *execute* (more than once if you like) and get back a `String` (if you execute it more than once than those may be different) - you can join/bind/compose together those *actions* (that's the monad part) and one way of doing this is the `do`-block syntactic sugar - but in the end you will only execute those actions when the runtimes execute the `main :: IO ()` *action*

Comment: @chi yes thanks - in this case I only copy&pasted the code

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another way to parse `IO String` into `String`?

No, there is no safe way of turning `IO String` into `String`.  This is the *point* of the `IO` type!

> now playerAnswer has type `IO String` so do i have to call `isCorrect` inside the `do` block ? [...] In case of first i am feeling like loosing all the benefits from functional programming because i will end up writing my entire code in do blocks in order to access the `String` value

That's what it looks like at first, but it's not like that.  The trick is that we use **adapter** functions to connect the pure and the effectful worlds.  So for example, suppose you have:

- A question `question :: IO Question`
- An answer `answer :: IO String`

And you want to call `isCorrect :: Question -> String -> Bool` on the `Question` and the `String`.  One way to do this is to use the `liftA2` function:

```
import Control.Applicative (liftA2)

example :: IO Bool
example = liftA2 isCorrect question answer
  where question :: IO Question
        question = _
        answer :: IO String
        answer = _
```

`liftA2` has this generic type:

```
liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
```

In this example, we're using it with:

- `f := IO`
- `a := Question`
- `b := String`
- `c := Bool`

So what liftA2 does is **adapt** a pure function to work with side-effecting types.  And that's how Haskell programming generally works:

1. You try to write most of your code as pure functions
2. You use auxiliary functions like `liftA2` to adapt them to work with impure effects.

It takes some study and practice to get the hang of this.

Comment: Sorry, but that's a bad example. The `Question` is already known at that point. `liftM (isCorrect question) getAnswer` or `fmap (isCorrect question) getAnswer` would be better, unless your `question :: IO Question` is the slightly bogus `putQuestion q >> return q`. Also, you're using the already existing function `answer` in a local binding, shadowing the `answer :: Question -> String` OP provided in his question. The overall mentality/paradigm of your answer holds, but that example is probably confusing for a language beginner.