# Haskell How to store a return value and match it with a regular expression?

Tags: haskell

This line of code should return a string but it returns IO(String).

simpleHTTP (getRequest "http://www.haskell.org/") >>= fmap (take 100) . getResponseBody

How can I pass the return value from the line above to getAllTextMatches?

```
import Network.HTTP
import Text.Regex.Posix

search :: String -> IO(String)
search url = do
 let link = (simpleHTTP (getRequest url) >>= fmap (take 50000). getResponseBody) 
 getAllTextMatches (link =~ "(<[a-zA-Z]+>)|(<[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*\s)" :: AllTextMatches [] String)
```

Comment: "Should" is a tricky word. I don't share your moral sensibilities: this line of code should return an `IO String`. But more to the point, what is your question?

Comment: I am trying to get the body of the url. 
The body should start with 
<!doctype html> ... 
I need to find all the tags in the body. 
How to get the return value from 
simpleHTTP (getRequest "http://www.haskell.org/") >>= fmap (take 100) . getResponseBody
and pass it as an argument to getAllTextMatches so that it will return a list of string to me.

Comment: You can't (well, shouldn't... by my moral sensibilities) give that functionality a return type of `[String]`, but `IO [String]`. Happily the response below happens to answer your question if you modify it in this way.

Comment: let f x = getAllTextMatches (x =~ "(<[a-zA-Z]+>)|(<[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*\s)" :: AllTextMatches [] String)
fmap f link -- IO [String]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7154518 .

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `<-` instead of `let`, `=` in the first line

```
let link = (simpleHTTP (getRequest url) >>= fmap (take 50000). getResponseBody)
```

should be

```
link <- simpleHTTP (getRequest url) >>= fmap (take 50000). getResponseBody
```

This is because you are communicating with the outside world, and this all needs to happen in the IO monad.

Then link will be a `String`, and you can treat it as such.

At the end of the function you will want to `return` a type `String` also.

---

Update-

Here is an actual snippet that compiles for me:

```
search :: String -> IO [String]
search url = do
  link <- (simpleHTTP (getRequest url) >>= fmap (take 50000). getResponseBody) 
  return $ getAllTextMatches (link =~ "(<[a-zA-Z]+>)|(<[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*\\s)" :: AllTextMatches [] String)
```

Note that `getAllTextMatches` returns an list of `String`, not a single `String`, so I had to change the type of `search` to `String->IO [String]`.  If you want to preserve the type, you will have to change the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot 
I did what you told me . 
But this line gives me an error 
startOn :: String -> String

Comment: @user3105629 I don't see any `startOn` function in your code snippet. Please add necessary code or no one will be able to help you.

Comment: I meant seach instead of startOn. 
That's all my code in the snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the `Monad` typeclass the `>>=` operator (pronounced *bind*) is defined as

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

where `m` is some monad. In your example `simpleHTTP (getRequest url)` is the `m a` part of the definition and `fmap (take 50000) . getResponseBody` is the `(a -> m b)` part. `>>=` operates "inside" the `IO` monad as your question suggests, so the result of `>>=` is of type `IO x` (replace `x` with `String` in your example). To extract the underlying value from a monad inside a `do` block, use `<-`, like so:

```
link <- (simpleHTTP (getRequest url) >>= fmap (take 50000). getResponseBody)
```

Comment: When I pass link to the function getAllTextMatches, it gives me an error. 
I know that linke has a type IO[String]. How do I convert it to string?

Comment: @user3105629 I'm confused. Both answers state how to make `link` a string. Your problem lays elsewhere. Please update the question with the full compiler error message.

Comment: Sorry for the wordings. The question I asked  has two parts. 
The first part is asking how to get the return value from simpleHttp line. You all answered me. But the second part of the question I asked is asking how to pass the return value to getAllTextMatches. Thanks