# Perform IO action, but return other type

Tags: haskell, io

For a project we were given the task to write an imperative language and execute it via Haskell. The parser (omitted here) and parts of the evaluation are done. Now only remains to code the effects. Manipulating a little robot.

Given the following code:

```
data Env = Env [Binding]
instance Show Env where
  show (Env (x:xs)) = show x ++ ", " ++ show (Env xs)
  show (Env []) = ""

data Binding = Binding (String,Int)
instance Show Binding where
  show (Binding x) = fst x ++ " : " ++ show (snd x)

lookup' :: String -> Env -> Int
lookup' zoek (Env env) = case elemIndex zoek [fst x | Binding x <- env] of
  Just y ->  y
  Nothing -> error "Not found"


eval :: Stmt -> Env ->  Env
eval (Seq s) env = foldl (flip eval) env s
eval (Assign varName aexpr) env = evalAssign varName aexpr env
eval (If bool stmt1 stmt2) env = evalIf bool stmt1 stmt2 env
eval (While bool stmt) env = undefined
eval (MotorInstruct string aExpr) env = undefined
eval (SensorRead string) env = undefined
eval Skip env = env

evalAExpr :: AExpr -> Env -> Int
evalAExpr (IntConst int) _  = fromInteger int
evalAExpr (Neg a) env = - evalAExpr a env
evalAExpr (ABinary Add a b) env = evalAExpr a env + evalAExpr b env
evalAExpr (ABinary Subtract a b) env = evalAExpr a env - evalAExpr b env
evalAExpr (ABinary Multiply a b) env = evalAExpr a env * evalAExpr b env
evalAExpr (ABinary Divide a b) env = evalAExpr a env `div` evalAExpr b env
evalAExpr (Var x) env = getElementAtEnv env (lookup' x env)
  where
    getElementAtEnv (Env env) index = getSndFromBinding (env !! index)
    getSndFromBinding (Binding (_,t)) = t


evalBExpr :: BExpr -> Env -> Bool
evalBExpr (BoolConst bool) _ = bool
evalBExpr (Not expr) env = not $ evalBExpr expr env
-- Boolean operators
evalBExpr (BBinary And a b) env = evalBExpr a env && evalBExpr b env
evalBExpr (BBinary Or a b) env = evalBExpr a env || evalBExpr b env
-- Relational operators
evalBExpr (RBinary Greater a b) env = evalAExpr a env > evalAExpr b env
evalBExpr (RBinary Less a b) env = evalAExpr a env < evalAExpr b env
evalBExpr (RBinary Equal a b) env = evalAExpr a env == evalAExpr b env


evalIf ::  BExpr -> Stmt -> Stmt -> Env -> Env
evalIf expr s1 s2 env = if evalBExpr expr env
  then
    eval s1 env
  else
    eval s2 env


evalAssign :: String -> AExpr -> Env -> Env
evalAssign term s (Env env)= if term `elem` transform
  then
    Env ( take (lookup' term (Env env)) env ++ [Binding (term, evalAExpr s (Env env))]++ drop (lookup' term (Env env) + 1) env)
  else
    Env (env ++ [Binding (term, evalAExpr s (Env env))])
  where transform = [ fst ele | Binding ele <- env]


zoekMotor :: String -> Int
zoekMotor "left" = 0x9
zoekMotor "right" = 0xa
zoekMotor _ = error "No such motor"


sendToMotor :: String -> Int -> IO()
sendToMotor m s = do
  bot <- openMBot
  sendCommand bot $ setMotor (zoekMotor m) s s
  closeMBot bot

evalMotorInstruct :: String -> AExpr -> Env -> Env
evalMotorInstruct welke waarde env = do
  sendToMotor welke (evalAExpr waarde env)
  return env
```

How would I go about executing the function `sendToMotor` (which returns `IO()`) in my evaluating function `evalMotorInstruct` which should return an `Env`? I'm somewhat to a loss as to how I would execute my 'action' - function and only get my `Env` back out of the evaluation function.

Note that the current code for `evalMotorInstruct` is not correct. The function is supposed to return an `Env`, but actually returns an `IO Env`

Thank you

Comment: You have discovered one of the interesting properties of Haskell—its purity. You cannot perform an IO action and return a result *not* wrapped in IO. This is because Haskell functions cannot perform arbitrary side effects; they must be pure. You *could* return an `IO Env`, which seems to be what you’re looking for here, based on your use of `do` and `return`.

Comment: @AlexisKing Does this mean I should convert all my other "eval" functions to return IO Env's too? And "unwrapping" them in every situation ?

Comment: You might want to look into using a free monad to avoid committing to `IO`.  http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html

Comment: @AlexisKing , I tried messing with the code some more to have eg `evalAssign` returning and acception `IO Env`'s. I did not succeed :/ . Could you provide some examples / help for my problem, if possible.

Comment: It takes a certain number of scraped knees to figure out how to keep pure code pure and confine the `IO` business to the periphery. I may try to write an answer later, but that may be better left to a more experienced teacher than me.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7154518 .

Answer (score 2):

Your AExpr and BExpr types represent pure computations in your language - not only don't they do any IO, but they also don't modify the environment. Consequently you shouldn't have to modify their eval functions.

So you just have to modify the evalution of `Stmt` values. The type signature will change to:

```
eval :: Stmt -> Env -> IO Env
```

An example of how `eval Seq` will change:

```
eval (Seq []) env     = return env
eval (Seq (s:ss)) env = do env' <- eval s env  -- eval the first statement
                           eval (Seq ss) env'  -- eval the rest
```

Note that `eval If` doesn't need to change:

```
eval (If bool stmt1 stmt2) env = 
  if evalBExpr bool env
    then eval stmt1 env
    else eval stmt2 env
```

`evalMotorInstruct` will compile if you change it's signature to:

```
evalMotorInstruct :: String -> AExpr -> Env -> IO Env
```

I'll leave the rest to you.

When refactoring, just comment out the code which doesn't compile. Then incrementally add the lines back in one-by-one getting each to compile before adding another line. Use `... = undefined` if you need to. Come back and fill those in later.

Comment: A potential improvement over this would be to use `StateT Env IO` as the monad, which would allow you omit passing around the `Env` by hand, and also you could write `eval (Seq ss) = mapM_ eval ss` etc.