# Perform an IO action in a non IO environment

Tags: haskell

I've gotten stuck on the following predicament.

```
evalAExpr :: AExpr -> Env -> Int
evalAExpr (Var x) env = actAccordingly (getValueOfBinding env x)
  where
    actAccordingly (Left int) = int
    actAccordingly (Right stmt) = eval stmt env

eval :: Stmt -> Env ->  IO Env`

getValueOfBinding :: Env -> String -> Either Integer Stmt
```

So what needs to happen is that with the Stmt `x` gotten from the Either Monad, it should evaluate `x` (which needs to happen in an `IO`, because of other processes) into a new Environment, after which I can return the correct value from the environment. However, from my limited knowledge of Haskell I can't ever get out of an `IO`.

Eg: `givetheCorrectThing nameOfTheValueInTheEnv (eval stmt env)` would never work with the current code, since all `evalAExpr` functions (yes there are more than just 1) return an Env atm. If I would have to change that, it would result in adding in ALL of the evaluation do and return statements. > 50-60 occurences. For sure. That would make code so messy to look at. The reason I need IO is because this evaluation will have to go (at some point) and collect data from an mBot (http://makeblock.com/mbot-stem-educational-robot-kit-for-kids/), aswell as collect data from the keyboard (done via getLine)

Would any of you have a way to rework this code so that I can keep it neat and organised?

If more code is needed: Feel free to ping / mention me. I will provide the requested lines of code.

More code as requested:

```
-- Code that shows how EvalAExpr is used.

-- Relational operators
evalBExpr (RBinary Greater a b) env = evalAExpr a env > evalAExpr b env
evalBExpr (RBinary Less a b)    env = evalAExpr a env < evalAExpr b env
evalBExpr (RBinary Equal a b)   env = evalAExpr a env == evalAExpr b env
```

Comment: If a function performs IO, it _has_ to return an IO type. Otherwise, the type is promising that the function is side-effect free, and if this is a lie, you compiler will spot it. There's no reasonable way around this but to add IO to the type of any IO-performing function.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you need to use IO in your evaluation routine. There might be alternatives...

Comment: Can you give examples of what your language looks like? Is it just a conventional Python / Javascript-like imperative language?

Comment: @ErikR: `x := 2` Assign value 2 to "x" in the environment; `if x > 1 then y := 3 else z := 4; n := 22` Basic if. Else branch is forced, but there is a skip statement included. Multiple statements in a row need to seperated by `;`. `While x do y done` where x is a boolean expression and Y are a sequence of statements. And then various `read X` or `set Y` commands to set and grab data from / on the robot. Have been working some more now, but as it's getting late. Gonna go to bed and test things in the morning.

Comment: See this pastebin for a way to segregate your interpreter into pure and monadic components. Not necessarily recommending this approach, but perhaps it gives you some ideas: http://lpaste.net/176816

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37532120 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a monadic version of `evalAExpr`

We'll call the new version `evalAExprIO`:

```
evalAExprIO :: AExpr -> Env -> IO Int
 evalAExpr (Var x) env = actAccordingly (getValueOfBinding env x)
  where
    actAccordingly (Left int) = return int
    actAccordingly (Right stmt) = eval stmt env
```

There is really only one significant change -- in the `Left` case the
function `actAccordingly` uses `return int` instead of just `int`.

The type signature for `evalAExprIO` has changed, but this is something
that GHC can infer so it's not something you have to know how to change.

**Update**

Change:

```
evalBExpr (RBinary Greater a b) env = evalAExpr a env > evalAExpr b env
```

to:

```
evalBexpr (RBinary Greater a b) env = liftM2 (>) (evalAExpr a env) (evalExpr b env)
```

(import Control.Monad for liftM2.)

Comment: But how do I plug that IO int back into my function that gives back a normal int?

Comment: Show us some code that calls `evalAExpr` and we can tell you have to change it.

Comment: See original post. Added more code that uses EvalAExpr at the bottom. I'm pretty sure i'm just supposed to write do return everywhere in order to make the types match?

Comment: While I agree with the general approach, I would encourage the use of `Applicative`. Example: `evalBExpr (...) env = (>) <$> evalAExpr a env <*> evalAExpr b env`. Easier to adapt, easier to read, and a great tool to know. And/or create a helper function: `evalBExpr (...) = evalWith2 (>) a b`

Comment: @MarLinn , will definetely try and do that tomorrow morning (late night already). Your suggestion would make the code so much more compact and readable.

Answer (score 2):

> from my limited knowledge of Haskell I can't ever get out of an IO

Correct<sup>†</sup>! And for good reasons: with the current signature, anybody using your function knows that this really is just a pure, referentially transparent calculation, so they can be accordingly careless with it (lazyness etc.). If you were allowed to just put in some `IO` without making this explicit through the signature, you might easily break everybody's code!

Of course, if you've only just noticed that you need to do IO, then you are indeed in a bit of a dilemma. There's no good way for you to get around changing all the signatures now.

However, you could have prevented this by using a type synonym<sup>‡</sup> in the first place: if you'd had originally

```
type Evaluation a = Identity a

-- ... lots of functions with an `Evaluation` result ...

evalAExpr :: AExpr -> Env -> Evaluation Int
evalAExpr (Var x) env = actAccordingly (getValueOfBinding env x)
  where
    actAccordingly (Left int) = return int
    actAccordingly (Right stmt) = someThingThatDidn'tYetRequireIO
```

then, upon noticing that you need `IO` after all, you could have just changed it to

```
type Evaluation a = IO a

{- same as before:
evalAExpr :: AExpr -> Env -> Evaluation Int
evalAExpr (Var x) env = actAccordingly (getValueOfBinding env x)
  where
    actAccordingly (Left int) = return int -}
    actAccordingly (Right stmt) = eval stmt env
```

In a big project, the `Evaluation` monad would then typically be a monad transformer stack, to which you'd just add an extra layer for the IO underneath.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>If anybody reminds me about the [function that shall not be named](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO), I shall whack them about the head [with a nuclear missile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/acme-missiles-0.3/docs/Acme-Missiles.html#v:launchMissiles).</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>As dfeuer remarks, a `newtype` may be better.</sub>

Comment: The fact that  this is an actual assignment and not just a project on my own means I won't even consider your little intervention with the nuclear missiles :P

Comment: I thoroughly agree with most of this, but not the type synonym advice. I have never seen anything good come from attempts to use type synonyms to maintain flexibility or enforce abstractions. That is what newtypes and type classes are for. Type synonyms are most useful as shorthand for complicated but concrete types, as are common in `lens`.

Comment: @dfeuer Then we must have very different development styles because I use them all the time and feel like I benefit greatly. Among the benefits are: Improved documentation in the type signatures; Placeholder for the "real" type of, say, an `OtherPlayerID`, a `Store` or a `Name` (`String` or `Text`?); improved readability if the type has many variables; Faster mental connection between a `Result a`, a `ResultM a` and a `ResultIO a`...

Comment: @MarLinn, I generally prefer to use newtypes for all such purposes. That makes it much easier to see just where I'm relying on relationships between the differently-named types. It also lets me know if I'm mixing up two types with the same representation. It guarantees that GHC will show the conceptual type name in its error messages and at the GHCi prompt. I don't think I've ever seen a Haskell beginner use a type synonym I approved of, and I've seen a great many advanced users write ones I disagree with. Even where I see their utility (as in `lens`), they also have serious downsides.

Comment: @dfeuer, interesting points. I think I'll experiment a bit more with both in the future. So thank you. I'm still not sure what I'd tell a "newcomer" about it, but, well, it's leftaroundabout's answer.

Comment: @MarLinn: yeah, I also do this type-synonym stuff quite a bit, hence my original suggestion. However, David is right that this can lead to several problems if you then actually refactor the types. Nothing to bad though – the Haskell adage mostly holds “[if you've refactored it and got it to type check again, then it'll work correctly](https://github.com/Gabriel439/post-rfc/blob/master/sotu.md#maintenance)”.

Comment: One problem with type synonyms is that they can give a false sense of security. When I write a type signature that looks like `f :: A -> B -> ...`, I generally just assume that if I mix up the `A` argument with the `B` one then I'll get a type error in almost all cases. But if either is a type synonym, then this assumption is totally wrong.